# link that moves you to div on same page that doesn't have ID (only class, and data-full)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

just as title reads. multiple "posts" that have a class that has a unique name, also a data-fullname that is unique as well. I know how to do this with IDs but don't know if you can otherwise.

sorry if this isn't specific enough. here's a fiddle that demonstrates the ID method: http://jsfiddle.net/avYBz/

Comment: did you try giving them unique id's with jquery after pageload?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am just putting the class inside the href.. You could do this various ways but the hyperlink needs at least one attribute that has the class of the element you are wanting to scroll to.

Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/lucuma/jK5T3/1/

```
<a href=".uniqueID"   >Go to post</a>

<div style="height:1300px"></div> 

<div class="uniqueID" id="1234">This is the post </div>​

$('a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var scrollto = $(this).attr('href');
    $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(scrollto).offset().top
        }, 1500);
});

​
```

I'm not 100% sure that a href can start with a period (with regards to being valid as the code works) so an alternate:

```
<a href="#" data-link="uniqueID"   >Go to post</a>
<div style="height:1300px"></div> 
<div class="uniqueID" id="1234">This is the post </div>​

$('a[data-link]').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var scrollto = '.' + $(this).attr('data-link');
    $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(scrollto).offset().top
        }, 1500);
});
```

Lastly you could append an anchor in each div and then use that in the href like a normal local hashed link.  Since all these solutions require javascript I'm not sure it really matters which you use but this solution keeps the href set to a valid local anchor that we've added to the page on load.  You can remove the click event in this part and it will still work  but the page will jump instead of scrolling nicely.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/lucuma/jK5T3/3/

```
$('#container div').each(function() {
   $(this).append('<a id="' + $(this).attr('class') + '" />');
});

$('a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var scrollto = $(this).attr('href');
    $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(scrollto).offset().top
        }, 1500);
});
```

​

Comment: excellent. i found a solution where I appended the unique class as an ID, but I like yours much better than I can animated scroll to it now. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I just updated the answer by adding an anchor with id. If you remove the click event (this does the smooth scroll) it will still work like the solution you probably found just to get them all in the answer.

Comment: @lucuma , with your first example, the screen is indeed scrolled to the element,but it will stop when the element is at the top of the page.If i want to stop when the element is at the middle? is any way to achieve this?